# How do I only inherit some variables from a super class in Python

Tags: python, oop

I am trying to make a subclass, Square, from a superclass, Shape.

```
class Shape :

     def __init__ (self, x, y) :
          self.x = x
          self.y = y
          self.description = "This shape has not been described yet"
      
     def area (self) :
          return self.x * self.y

     def describe (self, text) :
          self.description = text
```

I have tried

```
class Square (Shape) :

     def __init__ (self, x) :
          self.x = x
          self.y = x
          self.description = "This shape has not been described yet"
```

which seems to work, but the only thing that actually changes in Square is self.y = x, so I wonder if I could do the same thing without having to write self.x and self.description again.

(I tried doing something like this:

```
class Square (Shape) :

     def __init__ (self, x) :
          self.y = x
          super().__init__()
```

but, when I create a Square object, a type error occurs:
TypeError: **init**() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'x' and 'y')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Square` is a `Shape` whose `x` and `y` are the same.  Hence:

```
class Square(Shape):
    def __init__(self, x):
        super().__init__(x, x)
```

You just need to call `Shape.__init__(self, x, y)` with your `x` as both the `x` and `y` parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Just call the super function inside `__init__`. Put both the arguments equal to `x`.

```
class Square(Shape):
    def __init__(self, x):
        super().__init__(x, x)
```